# Taking a function as an argument in a python lambda function

Tags: python, lambda

I wanna make a python lambda function to approximate f'(x)....I first did it like

```
import math
backward_diff = lambda x,h: (x**2*math.cos(x) - (x-h)**2*math.cos(x-h))/h
print(backward_diff(1, 0.1))
```

and it worked, but now note x**2*math.cos(x) is a function f(x) so I want it to be also an argument like this:

```
import math
backward_diff = lambda f, x, h: ( f(x) - f(x-h) )/h
print(backward_diff(x**2*math.cos(x), 1, 0.1))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define another function

```
func = lambda x: x ** 2 * math.cos(x)
backward_diff = lambda f, x, h: (f(x) - f(x - h)) / h
print(backward_diff(func, 1, 0.1))
```

You can also use it without sending it as parameter

```
func = lambda x: x ** 2 * math.cos(x)
backward_diff = lambda x, h: (func(x) - func(x - h)) / h
print(backward_diff(1, 0.1))
```

If you don't want to define more than on `lambda` you can send `math.cos` as parameter, however you will have to leave the variables as duplicated code in the `lambda`

```
backward_diff = lambda f, x, h: (x**2*f(x) - (x-h)**2*f(x-h))/h
print(backward_diff(math.cos, 1, 0.1))
```

Comment: thing is the question asked is, write a function using pythons lambda to approximate f'(x) using the backward difference formula, the function must have 3 arguments f, x and h. so doing it like dat would mean I'm working with ONE f(x)

Comment: @Thembanator if you want a function as parameter in a function you need to define another function.